# Character controller is not centered to player model

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a player model from the unity third person starter assets, whenever I attached a Character controller component, the center of it seems to be at the feet. I know I can adjust the center in the component to fit the player model, but is there a reason why the center of the character controller is at the feet? I tried other player models and got the same results.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character controller is centered on the object's origin. For a rigged model that origin is typically the root bone located at the feet.

There is a special addon required to properly show bones in Unity, so I'll just display it in blender.

[image: rig of a tree monster with the rood bone highlighted to show the object origin]

One could make the argument that the character controller could take this into account and automatically compensate, however this isn't possible since not all models follow this standard as you can see with this popular Uganda Knuckels rig.

[image: rig of the Uganda Knuckels with the root bone highlighted. The origin isn't located at floor level.]

On top of that you might be using the character controller for a character that isn't humanoid. In such a case any attempt at automation would fail.